# Can't specify a path to install a dependency in the pubspec.yaml Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm very new to Flutter and I'm following the bloc Google login example so under `dependencies:` in the `pubspec.yaml`file I put

> flutter_bloc:
>       path: ../../packages/flutter_bloc

as in the downloaded project, but when I do get packages I get this error:

> Because fixit_cloud_biking depends on flutter_bloc from path which
>   doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_bloc at
>   "../../packages/flutter_bloc"), version solving failed. pub get failed
>   (66; Because fixit_cloud_biking depends on flutter_bloc from path
>   which doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_bloc at
>   "../../packages/flutter_bloc"), version solving failed.)

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't have the package `flutter_bloc` on the route you are defining.

The examples folder where you got the example uses local references, so if you didn't clone the entire repository or you are simply copying some parts to replicate it you must change the package path.

This way you will no longer use the local reference to the package, or you can correct the route.

So change this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_bloc:
    path: ../../packages/flutter_bloc
```

To this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_bloc: any
```

Please read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) for more information.

Comment: Oh I see..indeed inside the main repository there is a `packages` folder, hence it is finding it.  I actually did solve it by omitting the path altogether and specify the version as normally done. Thanks for the help. So with flutter_bloc: any what would I get? Would it install any version?

Comment: When using `any`, which is exactly the same as not putting any version constraint, the [pub’s version constraint solver](https://medium.com/@nex3/pubgrub-2fb6470504f) will resolve a version compatible with your code

I put `any`, since I don't know what version of the repository you are cloning, so that you will be able to run the example regardless of the version, since a compatible version will be resolved, but it is recommended to put the version constraints. [Here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints) you can read more about it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Giancarlo 
I'm just starting out and I wanna port my 35k lines of Swift to Flutter/Dart.. I'm giving myself a month.. I already got the Bloc concept under my belt and I find it so logic and helping keeping the code well structured.. Dough It's kind long

Answer (score 0):

You can specify paths using this example below. Obs: You need to respects spaces and break lines.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_bloc:
    path: ../../packages/flutter_bloc
```